# django get value from html

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I want to list all tables using my *Crawledtables*, and when i click table1 i need to pass in the *table_id*. With that *table_id* i need to get the *table_name* and list all the info inside that table. i m stuck at getting the table_id

this is my *views.py*

***EDITED views.py***

```
def table_base(request):
    table_name = Crawledtables._meta.db_table
    list_tables = Crawledtables.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'tables/table_base.html', {'table_name': table_name,
                                                      'list_tables': list_tables})


class AboutDetail(DetailView):
    model = Crawledtables
    pk_url_kwarg = 'table_id'
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AboutDetail, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        if 'table_id' not in self.kwargs:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=1)
        else:
            id_table = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['table_id'])
            return id_table

# need to create another fuction and i need to pass on the table_id     
# with this table_id i need to get the table_name
# need to use the table_name to get the content using
# Ex: test = AllTables.objects.all()
# i need to return the the content of the table id
```

this is my *table_base.html*

```
<br>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1> {{ table_name }} List</h1>
        {% if list_tables %}
        <table class="table table-bordered sortable">
        <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</a></th>
            <th>Date</a></th>
            <th>Search Button</th>
        </thead>
            {% for list in list_tables %}
            <tr>
                <td><pre><a href="#" >{{ list.id }}</a></pre></td>


                {# this is where i get the id of the table in CrawledTables and i set it equal to table_id #}

                <td><pre><a href="{% url 'tables:details' table_id=list.id %}" name="table_name">{{ list.name }}</a></pre></td>

                <td><pre>{{ list.date }}</pre></td>`
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
            {% else %}
            <p> No Records Found</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    </div>
```

and this is what i have for now for *table_list.html*

```
<table class="table table-bordered sortable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {{ context }}
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Url</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        {# make a for loop here #}
            <tr>
                <td> </td>  {# get the id #}
                <td></td> {# get the title #}
                <td><a href="" target="_blank"></a></td> {# get the url #}
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I ve tried to figure out without using requests or forms...i did get it...but i got stuck at creating a search engine...so now i have to go back to do it the right way using request and/or forms...
Please help me i really don't know what command i need to put...and those django docs don't really help me because its more about users and passwd and emails...

Thank you in advance

***UPDATE***
*models.py*

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Crawledtables(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField(db_column='Date', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'CrawledTables'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%name' % {'name': self.name}


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class AllTables(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(db_column='Url', unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True,
                           null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')

    class Meta:
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class TableIdForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name','date')
        model = Crawledtables

class AllTablesForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='title')
    url = forms.CharField(label='url', max_length=250)
    created_at = forms.DateTimeField(label='Created at')
```

Comment: add `models.py` file

Comment: i added the file :)

Comment: I don't understand the code you have posted. There is no form anywhere so nothing is making a POST request; and even if there was, nothing is calling the `addview` method. Your table_id will be passed in `self.kwargs`, as you know because you are already using it in `get_object`.

Comment: i do have a forms.py ( i added it just now).. how can i make it work...that function addview i only added just as an example of want i wanted...it doesn't have no code in it... This is my 4 try in getting this work...my last time i got it to work with no forms or request, but as i said....creating a search filter didnt work...

Comment: can you help me pls?